# Laravel handle custom Exceptions

Tags: php, exception, laravel-5

I want to handle custom Exceptions (PDOException, ...)

In App/Exceptions/Handler.php I add the following functions:

```
public function report(Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \PDOException) {
        //$this->renderHttpException($e);
        //Doesn't work
    }
    else 
    {
        parent::report($e);
    }
}

public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
        if($this->isHttpException($e))
        {
            return $this->renderHttpException($e);          
        }
        else 
        {
            return parent::render($request, $e);
        }
}

protected function renderHttpException(HttpException $e)
{
    if (view()->exists('errors.'.$e->getStatusCode()))
    {
        return response()->view('errors.'.$e->getStatusCode(), [], $e->getStatusCode());
    }
    else
    {
        //comes later
        return null;
    }
}
```

If I have a PDOException I can't handle it, because the PDOException doesn't look like a default Laravel Exception.

I know that it can't work, but I don't know how to make it work.

Here is the Laravel (5.1) Error:

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Exceptions\Handler::renderHttpException() must be 
an instance of 
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException, instance of 
PDOException given, called in /home/****/Workspace/****/app/Exceptions/Handler.php 
on line 37 and defined
```

The function source is from
[mattstauffer.co](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-custom-error-pages)

Comment: First of all you don't need to have else for if statements. Your report functions is correct but the commented line of code shows that you're calling renderHttpException with PDOException instance which is what the error about. Just put what you want to do with the PDOException under that function.

Comment: I removed the elese statement and redirect if $e is instance of PDOException, it works pretty nice. Thanks @CanCelik